# Simplefonts module issue with texlive 2022 (context)

Tags: errors, context

With old versions of texlive I had no problem with simplefonts module but after installing the new version (texlive 2022) errors appears when adding the module

```
tex error       > tex error on line 802 in file C:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/third/simplefonts/t-simplefonts.mkiv: ! Undefined control sequence


\simplefonts@fontfeature ...features \appendtocommalist \simplefont!localfeatures \simplefont!features \normalexpanded {\@NX
                                                                                                                             \definefontfeature [#1#2\s!features ][\namedsimplefontparameter {#1}{#2\s!features }][\simplefont!features ]}
\syst_helpers_comma_list_step #1->\def \currentcommalistitem {#1}\simplefonts@fontfeature {\v!mainfont }{#1}
                                                                                                            \ctxlua {thirddata.simplefonts.selectfont("\v!mainfont ","Latin Modern Roman","\simplefontparameter {#1\s!font }","#1","\simplefontparamete...
\17>>2 #1,->\syst_helpers_comma_list_step {#1}
                                              \syst_helpers_do_process_comma_item
<argument> \relax regular,
               italic,slanted,bold,bolditalic,boldslanted,caps, italiccaps,slantedcaps,boldcaps,bolditaliccaps,boldslantedcaps
\syst_helpers_do_process_comma_list ...}\syst_helpers_do_process_comma_item }\syst_helpers_do_do_process_comma_item_gobble #1
                                                                                                                             ,]\relax \global \advance \commalevel \minusone
\simplefonts@definetextfont ...ontparameter {##1\s!font }","##1","\simplefontparameter \c!weight ")}\stopprocesscommacommand
                                                                                                                             \ifx \currenttypeface \v!simplefonts \ifx \currentsimplefont \v!mainfont \doglobal \increment \simplefonts!mainfont \simpl...
```

**TeX file**

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
    
\starttext

hello 

\stoptext
```

Comment: As far as I have understood the simplefonts package is obsolete (since many years). At the [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Simplefonts_-_Old_Content) you get forwarded to the [definefontfamily](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfamily) page.

Comment: Thanks @mickep for your helpful reply.